# Menu driven Program not functioning

Tags: c, menu, return

I am trying to create a **Menu Driven** program in **C** but I unable to get back to menu after completing one function. How do I program it so that the program ask the user to continue or not after each function and return to menu?

```
//program of menu driven program
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int fac = 1, b, num, p, prime, click, out; //click for selecting the function and ext for goto
    while (1) {
        printf("Welcome to Varied Maths!");
        printf("\nYou can perform the following things here");
        printf("\n1.Factorial of a number\n2.Prime or not\n3.Odd or even\n4.Exit");
        printf("\nEnter your choice:");
        scanf("%d", &click);
        switch (click) {   //for seleting from menu
            case 1: //for factorial 
              printf("Factorial Calculator\n");
              printf("Enter the number:");
              scanf("%d", &num);
              for (p = 1; p <= num; p++) {
                fac = fac * p; //fac=1 which gets multiplied with the num entered the number gets increment and so on
                printf("Factorial of %d is %d", num, fac);
              }
              break;

            case 2: //prime numbers using for loop  
              //int prime,b,ent
              printf("Prime or not\n");
              printf("Enter the number:");
              scanf("%d", &prime);
              //int prime,b;
              if (num == 1) {
                printf("1 is Neither composite nor prime");
              }
              if (num == 0) {
                printf("Neithher compossite nor prime");
              }
              for (b = 2; b <= num - 1; b++)
                if (num % b == 0) {
                    printf("%d Not A prime", num);
                    break;
                }
              if (b == num) {
                printf("Prime Number");
              }
              break;
    
            case 3:
              int odd;
              printf("\nOdd or Even determiner");
              printf("\nEnter the number you want to know about:");
              scanf("%d", &odd);
              if (odd % 2 == 0) {
                printf("The entered number %d is a even number",odd);
              }
              if ((odd % 2) != 0) {
                printf("The entered number %d is a odd number",odd);
              }
              break;
    
            case 4:
              printf("\nThanks for Using Me.\nI would have been too happy if you checked out my functions ");
              break;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

What should I do? Should I use continue statement or anything else. Please Send Help

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Are you accounting for delimiters between parts of your input using `scanf`?

Comment: you have `return 0` inside your `while` loop, which unconditionally executes after the `switch` statement. You at least need to move that out of your loop. As mentioned, that would be easier to see with proper indentation,, make things easier on yourself. Or better yet, move `return 0` into `case 4:` so you quit when the user selects the option to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exit the `while(1)` loop from inside the `switch`, the best is to use a loop control variable:

```
int end = 0;
while (!end) {
    switch(...) {
        case 4:
            end = 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you want to use a `break` to exit the loop you can do something like that:

```
while (1) {
    switch(...) {
        ...
    }
    if (click==4)
        break; // that break will exit the active control block, here the current while
}
```